# Is there any way to reduce Metapsionic Costs?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation, optimization, psionics

I Already know of the Torc of Power Preservation and Earth Power and Metapower.
If it Matters the Character in Question(Though it isnt made yet.) is Level 10, has a Flaw which means he has 5 open feats. 6 if I decide he needs to be Human. Im leaning Twoard a natually Psionic Race however.

Are there any other Metapsionic Reducing Options besides those or am I stuck with them?

Comment: Are you asking this for a specific reason?  i.e. do you have a specific goal in mind?  Power Point Recharge (power cost reduction + Bestow Power) might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Dominant Ideal

[Mind’s Eye](http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/psm/20070629a)

The Dominant Ideal ACF for Ardents reduces the Metapsionic cost by 2 PP, and eliminates the need to expend Psionic Focus, when manifesting powers from the chosen Mantle. This is extremely powerful, especially with the Mantle Substitution options also suggested in that article.

## Midnight Augmentation

*Magic of Incarnum*

Doesn’t directly affect Metapsionic costs, but reduces Augmentation costs which will usually amount to the same thing.

### Also See: Psionic Tricks Handbook

On [Minmax Boards](http://www.minmaxboards.com/index.php?topic=1187.0).

Comment: I Suppose this is it then?

Comment: @Novian As far as I know and aside from the measures you listed in your question, yes. As it turns out, psionics is massively better-designed and more balanced than spellcasting largely because broken options like reducing meta costs are kept to a minimum.

Comment: I Suppose this is true.